# How to kill a battleship in Luftrausers?

Tags: luftrausers

How to kill a battleship in Luftrausers? Seems to be impossible to kill a battleship, how to hit it so it dies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the nuke body. Note that you need to die as well, so it's not a good way to deal with it.

Try a combination of Cannon + Melee + Underwater. I usually use this combination so I can just collide with sea-based enemies. Doesn't work really well for long-term survival though.

Answer (score 4):

You just have to keep hitting it, that's all there is to it. There is no special "trick" to it (other than avoiding getting killed yourself). Some weapons do better than others. (ex. The cannon won't take as many shots as the standard gun, and the shotgun will be somewhere in between)

Now just wait until the blimps. That's when it starts getting fun.